# Why it is giving undefined as value when trying to fetch from nearest li tag vendor_id

Tags: jquery

My HTML

```
<section id="Office" class="ulseWrap lielement activeRest ">
   <ul class="restListings">
      <div class="inner-intit">
         <sub class="sub">Yours Favorite Restaurant</sub><br>
         <li class="innerChild" user_location="Office" vendor_name="Raj Cool Drinks" vendor_id="1">
            <h6> Raj Cool Drinks</h6>
          </li>
         <input type="button" name="btn1" class="ordernow btn btn-success" value="Order Now" >
      </div>
   </ul>
</section>
```

When clicked on ordernow button , i need to fetch the li tags vendor_id

```
$(document).on('click', '.ordernow', function(event ) {
var  v_id = $(this).closest("li").attr('vendor_id');
alert(v_id);
});
```

Here is the link to the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/j2463tj3/

Comment: You need to clean up your code and use valid markup if you want predictable results. The only valid config of a `<ul>` element doesn't include having a `<div>` as a direct child. That all being said, your button doesn't have a direct `<li>` parent so why do you expect it to find one? From the jquery docs: "For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest will fetch you the nearest parent that is the `li` in theis case.

But here `li` is a sibling of the input element.

```
$(this).closest("li").attr('vendor_id');
```

Supposed to be

```
$(this).closest('inner-intit').find('li').attr('vendor_id');
```

**or**

```
$(this).prev('li').attr('vendor_id'); (If the input is always below the li)
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2463tj3/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use its css class name to find it if it is unique :

```
$(document).on('click', '.ordernow', function (event) {
  var v_id = $("li.innerChild").attr('vendor_id');
  alert(v_id);
});
```

or give it an `id` as in:

```
<li id="MyNameisLi" class="innerChild" user_location="Office" vendor_name="Raj Cool Drinks" vendor_id="1">
```

then call it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ordernow', function (event) {
var v_id = $("#MyNameisLi").attr('vendor_id');
alert(v_id);
```

});

so there is a lot of different ways to reach a destination.